# Is there a way to transfer resources from one island to another?

Tags: idle-worship

One of my islands has a lot of rock and wood that some of my other islands could use. Is there any way to transfer stuff? Or is there any way planned in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your dock and transfer there. You can transfer TO an island that doesn't have a dock, but not FROM an island that doesn't have a dock.